# SELECT specific rows when using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL table that keeps track of a user's score at a particular timepoint. A user can have multiple scores per day.

```
+-------+------------+-------+-----+
| user  | date       | score | ... |
+-------+------------+-------+-----+
| bob   | 2014-04-19 | 100   | ... |
| mary  | 2014-04-19 | 100   | ... |
| alice | 2014-04-20 | 100   | ... |
| bob   | 2014-04-20 | 110   | ... |
| bob   | 2014-04-20 | 125   | ... |
| mary  | 2014-04-20 | 105   | ... |
| bob   | 2014-04-21 | 115   | ... |
+-------+------------+-------+-----+
```

Given a particular user (let's say `bob`), **How would I generate a report of each user's score, but only use the highest submitted score per day?** (Getting the specific row with the highest score is important as well, not just the highest score)

```
SELECT * FROM `user_score` WHERE `user` = 'bob' GROUP BY `date`
```

is the base query that I'm building off of. It results in the following result set:

```
+-------+------------+-------+-----+
| user  | date       | score | ... |
+-------+------------+-------+-----+
| bob   | 2014-04-19 | 100   | ... |
| bob   | 2014-04-20 | 110   | ... |
| bob   | 2014-04-21 | 115   | ... |
+-------+------------+-------+-----+
```

`bob`'s higher score of `125` from `2014-04-20` is missing. I tried rectifying that with `MAX(score)`

```
SELECT *, MAX(score)  FROM `user_score` WHERE `user` = 'bob' GROUP BY `date`
```

returns the highest score for the day, but not the row that has the highest score. Other column values on that row are important,

```
+-------+------------+-------+-----+------------+
| user  | date       | score | ... | max(score) |
+-------+------------+-------+-----+------------+
| bob   | 2014-04-19 | 100   | ... | 100        |
| bob   | 2014-04-20 | 110   | ... | 125        |
| bob   | 2014-04-21 | 115   | ... | 110        |
+-------+------------+-------+-----+------------+
```

Lastly, I tried

```
SELECT *, MAX(score)  FROM `user_score` WHERE `user` = 'bob' AND score = MAX(score) GROUP BY `date`
```

But that results in an invalid use of `GROUP BY`.

- [Selecting a row with specific value from a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265054) is on the right track with what I am trying to accomplish, but I dont know the specific score to filter by.

EDIT:

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee6a2

Comment: Do you have a sql fiddle for this by chance?

Comment: No, I simplified my actual dataset for the question. I'll throw a fiddle together and edit the OP with it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get records with highest/smallest <whatever> per group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748986/get-records-with-highest-smallest-whatever-per-group)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want all the fields, the easiest (and fastest) way in MySQL is to use `not exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user_score` us
WHERE `user` = 'bob' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM user_score us2
                  WHERE us2.`user` = us.`user` AND
                        us2.date = us.date AND
                        us2.score > us.score
                 );
```

This may seem like a strange approach.  And, I'll admit that it is.  What it is doing is pretty simple:  "Get me all rows for Bob from `user_score` where there is no higher score (for Bob)".  That is equivalent to getting the row with the maximum score.  With an index on `user_score(name, score)`, this is probably the most efficient way to do what you want.

Comment: +1, nice one. (though you should change the `name` column with `user` and also add `us2.date = us.date`)

Comment: This is great, but it only returns the highest score overall, not the ones for each day

Comment: @johnluetke That's because you need to add `us2.date = us.date` to the condition

Comment: @Gordon Linoff i have seen your answers for such type of questions in which OP wants max row per group etc,your answers to such questions are mostly based on using exists approach so i want to know how this approach is efficient than join,also +1 for the effort

Comment: @Lamak . . . I was thinking "name is a better identifier than 'user' because I can't remember if `user` is a reserved word".  I convinced myself.  I also fixed the date issue.

Comment: @Lamak Oh, derp. Thank you. I'll run this against my data and see if it behaves correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `user_score` as a
INNER JOIN (SELECT `user`, `date`, MAX(score) MaxScore
            FROM `user_score` 
            GROUP BY `user`, `date`) as b
    ON a.`user` = b.`user`
    AND a.`date` = b.`date`
    AND a.score = b.MaxScore
WHERE a.`user` = 'bob'
```

Comment: Any chance for adding comparison how it compares in performance, idiomatic code etc with the selected answer?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an inline view and a JOIN operation. If there is more than one row with the "high score" value for a given day, this query will return all the rows.  (If `(user,date,score)` is unique, then this isn't a problem.)

For example:

```
SELECT t.user
     , t.date
     , t.score
     , t.`...`
  FROM user_score t
  JOIN ( SELECT d.user
              , d.date
              , MAX(s.score) AS score
           FROM user_score d 
          WHERE d.user = 'bob'
          GROUP BY d.user, d.date
       ) s
    ON s.user  = t.user
   AND s.date  = t.date
   AND s.score = t.score
```